# Command to find the time difference

Tags: linux, date, time, command

I have a log, which is dumped by 1 or more process simultaneously.
Sometimes, because of CPU over load and context switching, logging to this file will be 
delayed. I want to find the time difference between each line and print it before each line?

Log example:

```
07/18 16:20:29886564 Pid= 2998,Tid= 3036,  XXXXX.c:  335:XXXXX:### xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ### 
07/18 16:20:29886642 Pid= 2998,Tid= 3036,  XXXXX.c:  484:XXXXX:### yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy() 
07/18 16:20:29886880 Pid= 2998,Tid= 3036,  XXXXX.c:  488:XXXXX:>>>yyyyyyyyyyyyy() 
07/18 16:20:29887002 Pid= 2998,Tid= 3036,  XXXXX.c:  494:XXXXX:>>>OK: zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz()
```

I suppose that this could be possible with 'awk'. But, I am pretty bad at linux commands.
Could someone please help with this?

Comment: what kind of time format is `16:20:29886564`?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following `awk` command. I have commented it so you can understand how it works:

```
awk '{
  # split the time field
  split($2,arr,":"); 

  # convert hours and mins into seconds and compute total
  curr=arr[3]+arr[2]*60+arr[1]*60*60;

  # set previous value for the first line
  if(prev == 0) prev=curr;

  # print out the difference between current and previous totals
  print curr-prev,$0;

  # set previous to current
  prev=curr;
}' file
```